# loading in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to show a progress indicator like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is as below:

```
$i=0
$iMax = 10
do {
    $i++
    Write-Progress -Activity "Doing something awesome" -PercentComplete ($i/$iMax*100) -Status $i
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} while ($i -lt $iMax)
```

It would look as below:

[image]

Ref - [Write progress example](https://sharepointryan.com/2012/08/28/an-easy-example-of-write-progress/)

To use it with SharePoint, you can try the excellent example in the link below:

[An Example of Using Write-Progress in a Long Running SharePoint PowerShell Script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18697.an-example-of-using-write-progress-in-a-long-running-sharepoint-powershell-script.aspx#Example_PowerShell_Function)

Comment: thank you sir, this is not attached to the time required to execute the cmdlet! i want to show the progress till the cmdlet execution finished !!

Comment: you can modify the powershell script as per your requirement. Do check the above two links.